# Python 3.5: I am getting an error: "NameError: name 'multiprocessing' is not defined"

Tags: python, facebook, multiprocessing

I am getting an error:

```
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
NameError: name 'multiprocessing' is not defined
```

So, how to fix it ?  Thank you very much :)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#email").send_keys("myemail@gmail.com")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#pass").send_keys("mypassword")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#u_0_m").click()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
    pool.map(friend_uid_list, uid_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declared what *multiprocessing* is. You haven't imported the module either, you just imported *Pool* from *multiprocessing*. In other words, multiprocessing is not in your namespace, hence NameError. Try import the whole module and it should work.

```
import multiprocessing
```

Otherwise, since you imported *Pool*, you could just write:

```
pool = Pool(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `Pool`, not `multiprocessing`.

Replace `from multiprocessing import Pool` with `import multiprocessing`

Answer (score 0):

You have already `import Pool` from `multiprocessing`. So you need to replace the line

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
```

by

```
pool = Pool(5)
```